# modal is constrained to parent when backdrop-filter is applied

Tags: html, css

I made a modal (inspired by Daisy UI) and would like to give a backdrop filter to the container. To open the modal click the checkbox.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

#container {
  background: red;
  {% comment %} backdrop-filter: blur(16px); {% endcomment %}
}

.modal {
    pointer-events: none;
    visibility: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.modal-toggle:checked + .modal {
    pointer-events: auto;
    visibility: visible;
}

.modal-box {
    background-color: blue
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <input id="modal"  class="modal-toggle"  type="checkbox" value="off"/>
  <label class="modal" for="modal">
    <label class="modal-box" for=""> 
      modal-box
    </label>
  </label>
</div>
```

However, when I uncomment the backdrop-filter, the modal gets constrained to the container element. I don't want this. I would like the modal to fill the whole page, even with a backdrop filter on the parent.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

This example shows when backdrop is set as `position: absolute` to have it contained in the `container`, hopefully closer to the desired result.

Try scroll to see the elements behind the `container` blurred (only when the modal is visible).

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#container {
  background-color: rgba(220, 20, 60, 0.25);
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  padding: 30px 10px;
  isolation: isolate;
}

.modal {
  pointer-events: none;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.modal-toggle:checked ~ .modal {
  pointer-events: auto;
  visibility: visible;
}

.modal-box {
  padding: 25px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: #fff;
}

.backdrop {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  visibility: hidden;
  backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
}

.modal-toggle:checked ~ .backdrop {
  pointer-events: auto;
  visibility: visible;
}

.modal-toggle {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 50;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 12px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

section:nth-of-type(1) {
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/200?random=1);
  background-size: cover;
}
section:nth-of-type(2) {
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/200?random=2);
  background-size: cover;
}
section:nth-of-type(3) {
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/200?random=3);
  background-size: cover;
}
section:nth-of-type(4) {
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/200?random=4);
  background-size: cover;
}
section:nth-of-type(5) {
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/200?random=5);
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <input id="modal" class="modal-toggle" type="checkbox" value="off" />
  <figure class="backdrop"></figure>
  <label class="modal" for="modal">
    <label class="modal-box" for="">
      modal-box
    </label>
  </label>
</div>
<section></section>
<section></section>
<section></section>
<section></section>
<section></section>
```

**Original**

It seems that this is because parent with `backdrop-filter` will make `fixed` element placed relative to the parent element instead of the viewport. Accoding to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Containing_block#identifying_the_containing_block):

> If the position property is absolute or fixed, the containing block may also be formed by the edge of the padding box of the nearest ancestor element that has the following: ...

> ... A backdrop-filter other than none (e.g. backdrop-filter: blur(10px);)

Not sure if it would work in the use case, but a possible work around could be to have a separate element for the backdrop, perhaps such the following example.

Although not ideal, the separate backdrop here could still be further styled to be contained or offset from the `container` if needed.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#container {
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
}

.modal {
  pointer-events: none;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.modal-toggle:checked ~ .modal {
  pointer-events: auto;
  visibility: visible;
}

.modal-box {
  padding: 12px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: #fff;
}

.backdrop {
  /*  This could be absolute if the backdrop need to be contained */
  position: fixed;
  inset: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  visibility: hidden;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
}

.modal-toggle:checked ~ .backdrop {
  pointer-events: auto;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <input id="modal"  class="modal-toggle"  type="checkbox" value="off"/>
  <figure class="backdrop"></figure>
  <label class="modal" for="modal">
    <label class="modal-box" for=""> 
      modal-box
    </label>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks but that applies the blur to the backdrop. I want the blur to be applied to the panel on top.

Comment: @sryscad Thanks for explaining, because it's a `backdrop-filter` blur, did you mean to blur only something behind this panel when the modal is visible?

Comment: yes it is a sticky panel that blurs the rest of the page when it scrolls behind it. Then I added this modal and it broke. I see from the documentation you mentioned that there is indeed something wrong with the 'fixed' in .modal but I don't know how to force viewport-relative positioning.

Comment: @sryscad Then I think the effect of containing the `backdrop` inside `container` might be closer, I updated the answer to have another snippet for this change. Still just a work around but hope that it could help.

Comment: thanks, I would like the backdrop to be displayed always, so I removed ".modal-toggle:checked ~ .modal". This effectively fakes the blur by creating an extra element behind the sticky headerbar.

Comment: @sryscad Indeed that would work, actually if it always shows the blur effect (does not need to interact with the checkbox) then I think it could also be done with a pseudo-element on `container`. But again, keep an extra element makes it easier if later it does need to interact with other elements for some other effects.

Answer (score 0):

it will add a black transparent shadow at the full body but will not add the backdrop filter.

```
.modal-box {
    background-color: blue;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 5000px rgb(0 0 0 / 50%);
}
```

Comment: @ashan, thanks, but that doesn't solve my question